# :active for Menu links not working / non-clickable dropdown menu in mobile

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

I am finishing up a WordPress website (https://saltypack.com.au/) that I made using the theme Neve. The last 2 issues that I am having trouble solving are with the menu.

1. I want the font color in the menu to be #2088A0 on whatever page is active, and :active isn't working.
2. For the mobile Menu, I have "Services" as a dropdown menu and there is no Services page. On desktop, you can click "Services" and the dropdown appears. On mobile, you have to click the arrow icon for the dropdown to appear and clicking "Services" does nothing. I want both the arrow and "Services" to be clickable

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a trouble when you set a value for var , see at this line [image]

Comment: Thank you, I was able to add an active color! Now I just need to figure out the second part to make "Services" clickable in mobile.

Comment: The hover unfolding should be possible with CSS, if you want a clickable arrow that expands your navigation element, you will have to use some basic Javascript that adds a class to the element or parent-element you clicked.